# How to publish an Azure web app using management api?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I see how to list and even create web sites using the WebSiteManagementClient, but I cannot figure out how to publish content to an existing site. Am I missing it in the API, or is that just not supported right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deploy using the WebSiteManagementClient itself, although it can list the source control that you have configured for the site (i.e. git).

Here is a good list of how to deploy to a web app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/. Git is very easy to use and can be managed directly from the cmd line.

You can also consider using the Kudu REST API (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip). You can authenticate against this REST API using basic auth with credentials that you get from the publishing settings. If you're looking to programmatically publish, you can easily invoke a PUT request with whatever language you're using.